# SQL Server 2008 (SP2) Exception has been thrown by th target of an invocation (mscorlib)

Tags: sql-server-2008

The following error started after renaming my SQL Server 2008 (SP2) Instance with a new name.  Now unable to open the maintenance task that previously running with the old instance name, also the web applications are encountering a similar error.

SQL Server Error
        Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. (mscorlib)

Additional information:
  A network-related or instance specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.
  The server was not found or was not accessible.  Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL 
  Server is configured to allow remote connection. (provide: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40-
  Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error:53)

However, was told on a blog to drop the old instance name and rename with the new name, instructions followed; still having the same error.  Mean while, after droping the old name and SELECT @@SERVERNAME ---- It return a NULL.

Please can somebody help me.

Answer (score 1):

After much research I discovered renaming an SQL instance usually resulted to posted error. So, to avoid such situation, preferably, a new install of SQL is a best option, rather than renaming an instance, do a fresh install of SQL.